# Loss stuck from first epoch when using with float16 in 3D (Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've got a 3D segmentation task that I'd like to solve with a CNN in keras, using 64x64x64 patches. I know that float16 is more than good enough for the kind of data I've got in input. It's also more than good enough for the output, it's a segmentation, it could even be a uint8 (or a bool).
If I work with float32 my network works perfectly (I mean... as much as you can expect before optimizing it). I've tried switching to float16 for speed and... The loss gets stuck from iteration 0, the weights don't get updated etc... What am I doing wrong?
I've tried the following: changing loss function, changing optimizer, changing learning rate by many orders of magnitude. 
I've been able to reproduce the issue with a minimal example: a network with 2 layers, no downsampling, that has to learn to predict segmented masks from the masks themselves. Works fine in float32 not in float16. I'm working in Colab with default settings, therefore keras v2.2.5 and tensorflow 1.15.0

***EDIT:*** more updates The issue is most likely one of numerical precision in computing the loss function when using float16 and a 64x64x64 patch. When using 32x32x32 ones it does work.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Conv3D, Activation  

chosenDataType = 'float16' #swap between float16 and float32 to test
#set up a random, minimal 3D CNN
K.set_image_data_format("channels_last")
K.set_floatx(chosenDataType)
inputL = Input([64,64,64,1],dtype=chosenDataType)
l1 = Conv3D(32,[3,3,3],padding='same')(inputL)
l2 = Activation('relu') (l1)
l3 = Conv3D(32,[3,3,3],padding='same')(l2)
l4 = Activation('relu') (l3)
l5 = Conv3D(1,[1,1,1],padding='same')(l4)
model = Model(inputs=inputL,output=l5)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mse')
#create some fake black images with white spots
import numpy as np
import random
X_train = np.zeros([30,64,64,64,1],dtype=chosenDataType)
for imIdx in range(30):
  centPoin = random.randrange(20,44)
  X_train[imIdx,centPoin-10:centPoin+10,centPoin-10:centPoin+10,centPoin-10:centPoin+10,0]=1
#ask the network to fit the images themselves.
Y_train = X_train.copy()
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=30,epochs=100)
```

Comment: Does it completely halts like not responding or works in some way but no results showing up. Can we get your CPU and GPU usage at the time when it stucks. Also you GPU model if you are using tf-gpu.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, it's the loss value that is stuck. The fit function does run perfectly. But the loss doesn't move over epochs. After some tests I'm pretty sure that it's an issue with numerical precision when working with 64x64x64 tensors and float16. If I run the same code 32x32x32 matrices the model fits the data both using float32 and float16.